# executable compiled with VS 2015 much slower than with 2013

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, sdl

I am writing a graphical application using SDL2. I started the project in VS 2013 and it ran with about 30 fps. Now with the exact same code in VS 2015 I only get 8 - 10 fps.

To make sure it wasn't caused by moving the solution to a newer Version of the IDE I created a completely new project and only copied the source files. I even compiled the SDL libraries in VS 2015 but still much slower.

Can I do something to get better Performance or do I have to use VS 2013?

Comment: I have this problem too.  The same performance test project with the same project settings in VS 2013, release build, runs at about 53ms.  In VS 2015 it takes around 320ms.

Answer (score 1):

Are you comparing Debug or Release builds? Assuming you are comparing Release builds, the most likely explanation is differing compiler optimization settings between VS2013 and VS2015. Visual Studio has a fairly large number of compiler flags that can impact performance. Look at the property pages for your project, particularly at the options under `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization` and see if there are differences. Make sure you are comparing properties for the same configuration (Release vs. Debug).

If you find a Debug build is much slower, it is possible there are extra security / debug checks enabled in your VS2015 solution that are not enabled under VS2013. Compare the other settings under `Configuration Properties -> C/C++` and see if you can identify any differences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I was comparing the release builds. I had a look at the optimization Settings and everything is exactly the same :\          But I think I finally found the issue: functions like sin, cos, sqrt or pow returned floats in VS 2013 but doubles in VS 2015. Changing them to their float returning equivalent improves the Performance.